# SCCM LastLogonTimestamp format queried by PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell, sccm

I would like to know how it is possible to convert the LastLogonTimestamp found in the SCCM database to a readable format. The code I have now is the following:

```
$SCCMServer = 'SERVERSCCM'
$SCCMModule = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1'
$SamAccountName = 'test'

Function Get-SCCMSite { 
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$ComputerName
    )
    Process {
        Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Namespace 'root\SMS' -Class 'SMS_ProviderLocation' | 
            ForEach-Object{ 
                if ($_.ProviderForLocalSite -eq $true) {$SiteCode=$_.sitecode} 
        } 
        if ($SiteCode -eq '') {
            throw ('Sitecode of ConfigMgr Site at ' + $ComputerName + ' could not be determined.') 
        }
        else { 
            Return $SiteCode 
        } 
    }
}

Import-Module $SCCMModule
$SCCMSite = Get-SCCMSite -ComputerName $SCCMServer
Set-Location "$SCCMSite`:"
$SCCMNameSpace="root\SMS\site_$SCCMSite"

Get-WmiObject -namespace $SCCMNameSpace -computer $SCCMServer -query "select * from sms_r_system where LastLogonUserName='$SamAccountName'" | select *
```

The output of `LastLogonTimestamp` looks like this:

```
LastLogonTimestamp            : 20150330132039.000000+***
```

On the web I found that this format could be converted to a readable format like this:

```
[datetime]::FromFileTime(20150330132039.000000+***).ToString('d MMMM yyyy')
```

But it's not really working as it outputs errors. When I remove the last part behind the `.` it gives me a date in 1601, which is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `FromFileTime` method is the correct one for this situation.

You can use the `ParseExact` method with a bit of manipulation of the original value:

```
> $lastlogonstamp = "20150330132039.000000+***"
> $dt = [datetime]::parseexact($lastlogonstamp.split('.')[0],"yyyyMMddHHmmss",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
> $dt

30 March 2015 13:20:39

> $dt.ToString('d MMMM yyyy')
30 March 2015
```

Comment: ahh beat me to it. Nice one

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you arco444 :) I have to take into account that the SCCM server is also configured for another time zone. So need to compensate that to the time zone on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a WMI Object you can use

ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(lastLogonStamp);

In powershell I think it's